# 1 TB hardrive not giving all the space

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, disk-space

I have sort of a problem that I cannot seem to fix, my hard drive is 1 TB and is only displaying 565GB and 357GB aren't located to anywhere and particular and I would like to have the 931GB that shows in the disk manager. It says I have 931GB but the only space available in the computer is 565GB.

[image: Image showing disk manager]

[image: Space available in my computer]

Comment: Do you have data on either of the two partitions?   You could expand the disk, but if you have data on either partition it will be erased when you expand the drive.   Be sure to backup all of your data before attempting to make your dive one single 1TB partition.

Comment: The space totals to 931.51. What do you mean you cannot find it?

Comment: It sort of looks like you might have installed Linux at some time in the past based on the fact that Windows cant seem to detect the file system type for the other partitions.  Did you install Linux recently?

Comment: @Richie086 I't doesn't give me the option to expand the data on the Acer (C:) and doesn't give me no option in the 357 GB. Yes I already have data in the Acer (C:).

Comment: @Raystafarian I updated the post that should clear things up,

Comment: How you would accomplish this is you would need to format/delete the other partitions so they are available space, then when you click on C: you should have the ability to expand your C: drive, but be careful because if you delete the other partitions and they have data, you will have a hard time recovering any data on the 357.72, 7.87 and 500MB partitions.   The reason I think that it is Linux is the partition sizes, it looks like a 500MB swap space, 357GB root parition and some other partition.

Comment: @Richie086 I'ts a new computer, It only had windows 10.

Comment: They rest of the data is on line item #2 - it's not `C:\`

Comment: OK if you are sure, then right click on each other partition and delete it.   After you do that, it will appear as free space.  Then you can expand your c drive out to the full size.

Comment: @Richie086 If I expand my partion that as the biggest space, will something in it be deleted? and how can I find what is in the partion with 357GB ?

Comment: You cant, because windows cant detect a file system on any of those partitions.   If windows cant detect the file system, it can't read it.   Did you buy it used?   is this from school?   Is this a laptop you bought from some major retailer?

Comment: Before you do anything, do a full backup of all of your data or you very likely will end up loosing everything.

Comment: @Richie086 It's a laptop given to me by a company, that we can mess with in any manor, It came like brand new, but the company bought it from a major retailer.

Comment: Might want to check with your IT dept (if you have one) before going any further then.   If they imaged the laptop, they might be able to tell you why there are partitions on the computer that windows cannot read.   Is there any data on there that you absolutely cannot live without having?   If it were to be destroyed, would you loose your job or possibly be in any sort of trouble? If it is a brand new install and you are comfortable reinstalling windows yourself, then go for it.   But I would recommend contacting your companies IT dept if you have one to see what they say about it.

Comment: You need to either format and assign a drive letter to the second volume or delete the volume and expand the first.

Comment: @Richie086 well I'm a programmer in my company, the computer is our's to take home and mess with it, I just can't damage it physically, in terms of software is okay to mess with, so I can delete the 357GB, probably will assign the extra space when I need it, and thanks for the help with the problem, can you give a answer for me to close the topic?

Comment: Sure I'll post an answer momentarily

Comment: @Richie086 sure thing!

Comment: @luismontez Done!  glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to extend your C: drive, perform the following procedure:

1. Open **Windows Explorer** > right click on **Computer** > **Manage**
2. In the *Computer Management* window, left click on **Disk Manager**
3. In *Disk Manager*, right click on your 357GB drive and choose **Delete Volume**.
4. After the volume is deleted, it should show up as free space in the *Disk Manager*.
5. Right click on your C Drive in the Disk Manager, choose **Extend Volume.**
6. In the **Extend Volume** wizard, click **Next.**
7. You should see a 357GB portion of your disk available to add to your C: drive.
8. Click **Next**.
9. Click **Finish**.

Now your C: drive should be extended out another 357GB.   You can feel free to do this with your other partitions ***OTHER THAN THE 100MB PARTITION THAT SHOWS UP INFRONT OF YOUR C DRIVE IN THE DRIVE MANAGER.   YES, I AM WRITING IN CAPS ON PURPOSE.   IF YOU DELETE THE 100MB PARTITION, YOUR SYSTEM WILL NOT BOOT.***

I should not have to say this, but before attempting a repair like this you need to be sure you have a current full backup of all of your data.   If you do not have anything critical on your computer, and are comfortable reinstalling Windows then by all means do not bother with a full backup, but most people will have lots of documents, videos, pictures that they absolutely cannot loose.  If you are following my instructions in this answer and you are working on a computer issued to you by your employer, contact your companies IT dept and let them handle this issue.   If you do not know what you are doing, find someone who does that is willing to help.

Answer (score 2):

As someone else mentioned this might be a tool of your IT department. It sounds similar to something a friend told me about years ago.

A partition with it's own operating system and copies of all the apps that you might want but the company doesn't want to pay licenses for everyone. Also, IT diagnostic and recovery tools.

If you're on the road and discover a need for Oracle DB Server or AutoCAD then IT can have you boot the other partition, have it sync up to home, get new licenses and install from the copies.

Not saying it is that, but it is a possibility.

Comment: That could explain it, all right.  They could use a special boot disk or something like that.  It might even contain an image of the required software that needs to always be installed and working like a Workspace Manager or the like.  If that's what it is, then my answer below might piss someone off.  IT Dept-managed PCs shouldn't be repartitioned, that's for sure.  Upvote.

Answer (score 1):

I use the free [AOMEI Disk Partitioner](http://www.disk-partition.com/free-partition-manager.html) software for this, but the concept is the same.  It helps to get a visual look at what is on that drive.

Unused large partitions (the ones without drive letters) that are adjacent to C: can be deleted if they are not in use, then the C: drive can be expanded to use that space.  Just don't delete the small 100MB partition, of course.

It almost looks like this is a dual-boot system that has Linux using part of the drive.  But if it was new that makes no sense.  If it is not new and you simply want a bigger C: drive, then you can go for it.

As always, you should run a good backup of C: before any repartitioning.

Also, don't get confused about what 1TB means.  It is a marketing term.

If you multiply that 1TB = 1 Billion Bytes by (1000/1024) - the ratio of 1000 bytes to 1K bytes - you get 976.56 MB

Anywhere in that range of bytes can often be marketed as a 1TB drive.